# Подключение tinymce в модальном окне

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, tinymce

Пытаюсь подключить текстовый редактор tinymce во всплывающем окне bootstrap 3, все хорошо, но textarea пустой.

Вот код в хэдэре:

```
<script src="/admin/template/news2/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });</script>
<script>
    $('#add_new').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
 var modal = $(this);
 modal.find('#ntext').tinymce();
});

</script>
```

Без подключения tinymce все работает, но с ним нет. Что делаю не так?

Comment: в консоле не смотрели наличие ошибок?

Comment: Если понимаю правильно, то дописал console.log(); но это не выводит ничего в консоли хрома

Comment: Неужели никто не использует связку tinymce + bootstrap modal?

Answer (score 1):

Если пработает не в модальном окне а в модальном не работает - возможно причина может быть в том, что тини не хочет отрабатывать на скрытой текстарии, попробуйте
... .on('shown.bs.modal', ...

Comment: Спасибо, проблема решилась инициализацией при вызове модального окна в обработчике нажатия на кнопку вызова, через shown не пробовал